# Golang GORM and Decoding HTTP.Request.Body into JSON

Tags: json, go, go-gorm

I am trying to decode a json request (handled with gorilla/mux) into a struct and save it with GORM into a mysql database. I send the request with curl (see the cURL command). The request is invalid and should fail at 2 points 1) It should not decode into the struct 2) It should not be saved to the database. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and would appreciate help :)

The decoded struct looks like this:

```
{{0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>}   }
```

cURL command:

```
curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/dimoengra/subscribe
```

Code:

```
package subscribe

import "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
import "net/http"
import "encoding/json"
import "fmt"

// Subscription ...
type Subscription struct {
  gorm.Model
  ServiceID             string `gorm:"not null" json:"ServiceID"`
  MessageCode           string `gorm:"not null" json:"MessageCode"`
  SubscriberCallbackURL string `gorm:"not null" json:"SubscriberCallbackURL"`
}

// SubscribeHandler ...
func SubscribeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, db *gorm.DB) {

fmt.Println("Handle Subscribtion")

if r.Body == nil {
    http.Error(w, "Please send a request body", 400)
    fmt.Println("Empty body")
    return
}

var s Subscription
err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&s)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), 400)
    return
}
fmt.Println(s)

err = Subscribe(db, s)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), 400)
    return
}

}

// Subscribe ...
func Subscribe(db *gorm.DB, subscription Subscription) error {

err := db.Create(&subscription)
fmt.Println("err:", err.Error)
return err.Error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is valid JSON, so you won't get a JSON error. If the zero value for your struct is allowed by the schema, that's also valid, so you won't get an error from gorm. By all measures you're using, your input is valid. If you want additional validation, you'll have to write it into your handler.